# Permutations using Perl

Tags: perl, permutation

I am trying to write a simple recursive Perl routine to generate all of the permutations of an array.  I don't have any of the modules that provide routines for doing this and I can't install them either.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
sub permute
{
   my @array = @_;
   if (@array == 0)
   {
      return;
   }
   else
   {
      my $accum = "";
      my $result = permute_with_accumulator($accum, @array);
      return $result;
   }
}

sub permute_with_accumulator
{
   my ($accum, @array) = @_;
   if (@array == 1)
   {
      my $element = $array[0];
      $accum .= "$element,";
   }
   else
   {
      my $i;
      for ($i = 0; $i <= $#array; $i++)
      {
         $accum .= "$array[$i] ";
         my @new_array = ();
         if ($i == 0)
         {
            @new_array = @array[1..$#array];
         }
         elsif ($i == $#array)
         {
            @new_array = @array[0..$#array-1];
         }
         else
         {
            my $lower = $i - 1;
            my $upper = $i + 1;
            @new_array = @array[1..$lower, $upper..$#array];
         }
         permute_with_accumulator($accum, @new_array);
      }
   }
   return $accum;
}
```

But when I do @array = qw(e1 e2 e3 e4 e5) and run:

```
my $perms = permute(@array);
print ("$perms\n");
```

the output is just

```
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: If you can't install CPAN modules, you're missing half of Perl and tripling your workload.  I'd recommend fixing that, or you'll just have to reinvent and maintain more wheels.  Consider using something like local::lib to install modules without root, or perlbrew to compile your own copy of Perl.

Comment: So if I posted my code on StackOverflow, that's ok, but if I post it on CPAN, it's not?!?

Comment: I'm working on a lab computer and I am limited to what's installed.  I can't install anything myself.  As far as I can tell I have tried to "use" every module that would provide a routine for permutations but none are available.

Comment: @Schemer You can install modules yourself, even on a lab computer. Look at [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib) to get you set up to install modules for yourself without root permissions or [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) to compile your own copy of perl.  Neither of these require extra permissions, they all work within your home directory.  Unless this is homework and you're not allowed to use modules?

Comment: This is part of a much larger assignment that has to run as is on the university lab computer.  I could install modules into my home directory but they would not be available in the directory where the program will be run.

Comment: You can always look at the source code of modules on CPAN to see how they did it.

Comment: " I don't have any of the modules that provide routines for doing this and I can't install them either."  [Horse hockey!](https://metacpan.org/module/local::lib)

Answer (score 8):

Actually, this could be found in the FAQ:

[How do I permute N elements of a list?](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfaq4#How_do_I_permute_N_elements_of_a_list?)

Along with some nifty code for pasting:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
# Fischer-Krause ordered permutation generator

sub permute (&@) {
        my $code = shift;
        my @idx = 0..$#_;
        while ( $code->(@_[@idx]) ) {
                my $p = $#idx;
                --$p while $idx[$p-1] > $idx[$p];
                my $q = $p or return;
                push @idx, reverse splice @idx, $p;
                ++$q while $idx[$p-1] > $idx[$q];
                @idx[$p-1,$q]=@idx[$q,$p-1];
        }
}

permute { print "@_\n" } split;
```

This code is supposed to be used as a standalone script, but you can just use the sub directly with

```
sub permute (&@);  # predeclare sub, paste sub at bottom
my @a;
permute { push @a, "@_" } @some_array;
```

Comment: Actually, that line was always there.  What I fixed with the edit was the order of the parameters since that was screwing up the routine in a different way.

Comment: @Schemer But you do not return anything. Also, you are adding `$i` to your `$accum`, which is the array index, not the element.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that I was not adding the array element. :P  Typo.  I took the `return $accum` out of the base case and moved it to the end of the routine.  But now when I call permute on an array containing e1, e2, e3, e4, and e5 my output is simply `e1 e2 e3 e4 e5`.

Comment: @Schemer Yeah, I noticed that too.

Comment: Thanks.  I missed your comment the first time.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't read that to save my life!  I have copied the sub and the call to permute and then I have attempted your call with `my @edges = qw(e1 e2 e3 e4 e5); my @a; permute { push @a, "@_" } @edges;`.  But I get the error message: "Can't call method "permute" without a package or object reference at ./hamiltonian-a.pl line 17."  The Perl is way over my head so I can't diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Schemer That error means that the sub is not loaded in your current namespace. I assume you pasted the sub below your code. It's some weirdness going on with prototypes (the `(&@)` part) that the compiler is having trouble with. You can predeclare the sub at the top of your script with `sub permute (&@);` and things should work out.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice lecture on YouTube in the Stanford programming paradigms series about doing permutation with recursion and double mapping in Scheme. In Perl, I came up with the following implementation for the algorithm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw(e1 e2 e3);

sub permute {
    return ([]) unless (@_);
    return map {
      my @cdr = @_;
      my $car = splice @cdr, $_, 1;
      map { [$car, @$_]; } &permute(@cdr);
    } 0 .. $#_;
}

print "@$_\n" foreach (&permute (@array));
```

Might be very inefficient, but I thought it was fun & elegant :)